# Choosing different Version of a model

Tags: python, python-2.x

Is there anyway to improve with how this code is structured into functions? Is the coding style compliant, and what can be improved beyond this?

```
def add_lower_intuitive_relation(gurobi_model, Leg1, Leg2, lower_bound, eval_func, name=""):
    for first_departure in xrange(Leg1.latest_departure_time - Leg1.earliest_departure_time + 1):
        add_constraint = True
        linexprleft = gurobipy.LinExpr()
        linexprleft.addTerms(1.0, Leg1.gurobi_variables[first_departure])
        linexprright = gurobipy.LinExpr()
        for second_departure in xrange(Leg2.latest_departure_time - Leg2.earliest_departure_time + 1):
            if lower_bound <= eval_func(Leg1.earliest_departure_time + first_departure,
                                        Leg2.earliest_departure_time + second_departure, Leg1, Leg2):
                if second_departure == 0:
                    add_constraint = False
                    break
                linexprright.addTerms(1.0, Leg2.gurobi_variables[second_departure])
        if add_constraint:
            gurobi_model.addConstr(linexprleft,gurobipy.GRB.LESS_EQUAL,linexprright,name)


def add_lower_tu_relation(gurobi_model, Leg1, Leg2,lower_bound, eval_func, name=""):
    linexpr_cummulative = gurobipy.LinExpr()
    for first_departure in xrange(Leg1.latest_departure_time - Leg1.earliest_departure_time + 1):
        linexpr_cummulative.addTerms(1.0, Leg1.gurobi_variables[first_departure])

    for first_departure in xrange(Leg1.latest_departure_time - Leg1.earliest_departure_time + 1):
        add_constraint = True
        linexprright = gurobipy.LinExpr()
        for second_departure in xrange(Leg2.latest_departure_time - Leg2.earliest_departure_time + 1):
            if lower_bound <= eval_func(Leg1.earliest_departure_time + first_departure,
                                        Leg2.earliest_departure_time + second_departure, Leg1, Leg2):
                if second_departure == 0:
                    add_constraint = False
                    break
                linexprright.addTerms(1.0, Leg2.gurobi_variables[second_departure])
        if add_constraint:
            gurobi_model.addConstr(linexpr_cummulative,gurobipy.GRB.LESS_EQUAL,linexprright,name)
        linexpr_cummulative.addTerms(-1.0, Leg1.gurobi_variables[first_departure])


def add_upper_tu_relation(gurobi_model, Leg1, Leg2, upper_bound, eval_func, name=""):
    linexpr_cummulative = gurobipy.LinExpr()
    for second_departure in xrange(Leg2.latest_departure_time - Leg2.earliest_departure_time + 1):
        linexpr_cummulative.addTerms(1.0, Leg2.gurobi_variables[second_departure])

    for second_departure in xrange(Leg2.latest_departure_time - Leg2.earliest_departure_time + 1):
        add_constraint = True
        linexprright = gurobipy.LinExpr()
        for first_departure in xrange(Leg1.latest_departure_time - Leg1.earliest_departure_time + 1):
            if eval_func(Leg1.earliest_departure_time + first_departure,
                         Leg2.earliest_departure_time + second_departure, Leg1, Leg2) <= upper_bound:
                if second_departure == 0:
                    add_constraint = False
                    break
                linexprright.addTerms(1.0, Leg1.gurobi_variables[first_departure])
        if add_constraint:
            gurobi_model.addConstr(linexpr_cummulative,gurobipy.GRB.LESS_EQUAL,linexprright,name)
        linexpr_cummulative.addTerms(-1.0,Leg2.gurobi_variables[second_departure])


def add_lower_relation(gurobi_model, Leg1, Leg2,lower_bound, eval_func, args, name=""):
    if args.improved_timetable_formulation == "0":
        add_lower_intuitive_relation(gurobi_model,Leg1,Leg2,lower_bound,eval_func,name="")
    else:
        add_lower_tu_relation(gurobi_model,Leg1,Leg2,lower_bound,eval_func,name="")


def add_lower_and_upper_intuitive_relation(gurobi_model, Leg1, Leg2, lower_bound, upper_bound, eval_func, name=""):
    for first_departure in xrange(Leg1.latest_departure_time - Leg1.earliest_departure_time + 1):
        linexprleft = gurobipy.LinExpr()
        linexprleft.addTerms(1.0, Leg1.gurobi_variables[first_departure])
        linexprright = gurobipy.LinExpr()
        for second_departure in xrange(Leg2.latest_departure_time - Leg2.earliest_departure_time + 1):
            distance = eval_func(Leg1.earliest_departure_time + first_departure,
                                 Leg2.earliest_departure_time + second_departure, Leg1, Leg2)
            if lower_bound <= distance and distance <= upper_bound:
                linexprright.addTerms(1.0, Leg2.gurobi_variables[second_departure])
        gurobi_model.addConstr(linexprleft,gurobipy.GRB.LESS_EQUAL,linexprright,name)


def add_lower_and_upper_tu_relation(gurobi_model, Leg1, Leg2, lower_bound, upper_bound, eval_func, name=""):
    add_lower_tu_relation(gurobi_model,Leg1,Leg2,lower_bound,eval_func,name)
    add_upper_tu_relation(gurobi_model,Leg1,Leg2,upper_bound,eval_func,name)


def add_lower_and_upper_relation(gurobi_model, Leg1, Leg2, lower_bound, upper_bound, eval_func, args, name=""):
    if args.improved_timetable_formulation == "0":
        add_lower_and_upper_intuitive_relation(gurobi_model, Leg1, Leg2, lower_bound, upper_bound, eval_func, name="")
    else:
        add_lower_and_upper_tu_relation(gurobi_model,Leg1,Leg2,lower_bound,upper_bound,eval_func,name="")


def minimium_waiting_time_eval_func(depart1, depart2, Leg1, Leg2):
    return depart2 - (depart1 + Leg1.travel_time)


def minimium_headway_depart_time_eval_func(depart1, depart2, Leg1, Leg2):
    return depart2 - depart1


def minimium_headway_arrival_time_eval_func(depart1, depart2, Leg1, Leg2):
    return (depart2 + Leg2.travel_time) - (depart1 + Leg1.travel_time)


def connection_time_eval_func(depart1, depart2, Leg1, Leg2):
    return depart2 - (depart1 + Leg1.travel_time)
```

`add_lower_relation` calls either `add_lower_intuitive_relation` or `add_lower_tu_relation` depending on the given arguments `args`.

add_lower_and_upper_relation calls `add_lower_and_upper_tu_relation` or `add_lower_and_upper_intuitive_relation`.

I have a one line function to pass the `eval_func` to the functions. I wanted this so the function is easily extend to different eval_functions.

Comment: Can you add a brief description in question as to what this code is supposed to do? What problem it is trying to solve?

Comment: The code is constructing a Model for the solver Gurobi, depending on the variable args.improved_timetable_formulation it chooses one of two formulations (intuitive or tu)

Answer (score 2):

This code is rather hard to read and this is due to the following issues:

- *Vertical spacing at a minimum* – It's hard to differentiate the different blocks from each other as everything is thrown together. Adding some blank lines here and there would give some more air and ease the reading of your code
- *Horizontal spacing at a minimum* – In some spaces you do have space after commas, but mostly you don't. Please do include space after commas
- *No comments or description* – There is no indication in your code as to what the different parts are supposed to do, and with (for me at least) a new library like gurobipy, this makes it very hard to see the connections in the code and how the different parts relate to each other
- *Long and slightly confusing variables names* – Having good descriptive variable name can help readability. In your case the `linexprright` and `linexprleft` are not very helpful, and I do believe `right` or `left` would suffice, or possibly `left_expression` or `right_side` could be better.

  Similarily I would suggest using `tu_lower_relation` (what is `tu`) and `intuitive_range_relation` for the far too long relation function names. But that is based on limited knowledge of what they actually do.

Some more code related thoughts:

- *Use better range in `for` loops* – As suggested by pjz, it would most likely look better to use `xrange(firstLeg.earliest_departure_time, firstLeg.latest_departure_time + 1)` or similar. As depicted I would change from `Leg1` and `depart2` to either `firstLeg` or make it into an array and use `leg[0]` or `depart[1]`. In general, try to avoid using numbers in a variable name, and don't uppercase the first letter!
- *An exemplification of the `for ... else` structure* – The `else` clause of a `for` (or `while`) loop is triggered if the loop ends naturally, that is not exited by the use of `break`. This allows for code like:

  ```
  my_list = [2, 4, 6]
  for i in my_list:
      if i % 2 == 1:
          print("{} is not even".format(i))
          break

  else:
      print "All values in list are even"
  ```

  And this does look a lot like the `add_constraints` code you're using.
- *Use function aliasing directly* – Instead of introducing another layer of functions, use function aliasing directly in your main code somewhere, similar to what you do with `eval_func`. That is use something like the following at a higher level:

  ```
      if args.improved_timetable_formulation == "0":
          range_relation = intuitive_range_relation
          lower_relation = intuitive_lower_relation
      else:
          range_relation = tu_range_relation
          lower_relation = tu_lower_relation

      # And below that do the now one-level call
      range_relation(gurobi_model, firstLeg, secondLeg, 
                     lower_bound, upper_bound,
                     eval_func)
  ```
- *Consider using arrays or tuples to pass fewer parameters* – Maybe not applicable, but possibly you use named tuples, lists or classes to encapsulate more of the parameters passed into the functions.

Answer (score 0):

A few things jump out:

1. <del>`xrange()` is deprecated, just use `range()`</del>
2. Do less math; in particular try converting

   ```
   for second_departure in xrange(Leg2.latest_departure_time - Leg2.earliest_departure_time + 1):
   ```

into

```
    for second_departure in range(Leg2.earliest_departure_time, Leg2.latest_departure_time + 1)
```

and see what that change in the value of `second_departure` saves you in terms of complexity.

3. You can get rid of the `add_constraint` variable by using a [`for..else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: In Python 2.7 using `xrange` is **not** deprecated if the range is large, as it doesn't allocate the entire list like `range`does.

Comment: Wow, I really thought it had been deprecated a couple years ago.  I must have been confused by doing so in Py3k.  I updated the answer. Thanks!